# How to use cursor results in a query in stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to get the variable (ACTIVE_INVENTORY) value from sql query dynamically and use it in further below queries. But it seems to be giving error.

Please suggest how could a variable be used in following query.

Thanks

```
create or replace procedure sp()
returns table (vin varchar, listing_date date, sale_date date, active_inventory boolean)
language sql
as
$$
declare
  select_query varchar;
  SOLD_THRESHOLD_DATE date;
  c1 cursor for select max(sale_date) from TBL;
  res resultset;
begin
  open c1;
  fetch c1 into SOLD_THRESHOLD_DATE;
  select_query := 'select vin,listing_date,sale_date,
  case when 60 >= DATEDIFF(Day,sale_date,SOLD_THRESHOLD_DATE) then 1 else 0  end as active_inventory from 
  TBL limit 10';
  res:= (execute immediate : select_query);
  close c1;
  return table(res);
end;
$$; 

call sp();
```

> Uncaught exception of type 'STATEMENT_ERROR' on line 13 at position 9 : SQL compilation error: error line 2 at position 41 invalid identifier 'SOLD_THRESHOLD_DATE'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parametrizing the query:

```
select_query := 'select vin,listing_date,sale_date,
      case when 60>=DATEDIFF(Day,sale_date,?) then 1 else 0 end as active_inventory 
      from TBL limit 10';

res:= (execute immediate :select_query using (SOLD_THRESHOLD_DATE) );
```

Comment: Is there a way to use multiple such variables?

Comment: @arora "Is there a way to use multiple such variables?" yes, in query code the placeholder is `?` symbol and later `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ... USING(var1, var2, ...)`